# How to set up a new interface sharing the same physical NIC with eth0 to use a second IP address?

Tags: ubuntu, routing, interface

My ISP has bound a second real IP address to my dedicated server, but that new IP does not seem to function. How do I set up an interface for it?

I Use Ubuntu 10.04 LTS AMD64 Server OS.

Comment: Did you try `man ifconfig`? If you don't know what 'man' is try `man man`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the following config in /etc/network/intercaes:

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address ADDRESS
netmask NETMASK
broadcast BROADCAST
network NETWORK
```

Runtime:

```
ifconfig eth0:0 ADDRESS/NETMASK
```

such as ifconfig eth0:0 8.8.8.8/32

ADDRESS,NETMASK given provider